# parent - child inheritance management in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, namespaces, parent

I want to write inheritances in C# in one namespace.
They are three classes: IAccount, Account, CustomerAccount

I want to write them in different classes but it gives me this error message:

The type or namespace name 'IAccount' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I wrote these directives in the beginning of each class:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
```

Comment: just press ctrl+mouse click on IAccount and add the related namespace. The namespace of IAccount is missing in the class declared.

Comment: What namespace do your three types belong to? You need to add `using MyNamespaceBelongsHere;` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

These classes **most** probabbly stay into **different** namepsaces (casually or not). 
So

- or declare necessary namespace with others on top of the file with `using`
- or uniform all namepsaces within the same one (main program namepsace)